# 414 Request-URI Too Large - Is this browser dependant?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache

When i try to debug using Firebug , i saw this 414 error.

In IE 6 am getting error when  post 20 records, in Mozilla its more than 50,
in IE 8 more than 100.

When i Google it , i find it as server thing , something to do with Apache.

Am using Jquery , Ajax ,PHP combination.

Page redirect is also there after submission

Please share Any information regarding this error .

Comment: Sounds like you should be making a POST request instead of a GET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, depents on the browser. If you have such long url's you have a design problem anyway.

Found this on the internet, bit outdated but gives you an idea how long an url can be. If your posting data use the POST method instead of a GET.

> **Microsoft Internet Explorer (Browser)**
>
> Microsoft states that the maximum
> length of a URL in Internet Explorer
> is 2,083 characters, with no more than
> 2,048 characters in the path portion
> of the URL. In my tests, attempts to
> use URLs longer than this produced a
> clear error message in Internet
> Explorer.
>
> **Firefox (Browser)**
>
> After 65,536 characters, the location
> bar no longer displays the URL in
> Windows Firefox 1.5.x. However, longer
> URLs will work. I stopped testing
> after 100,000 characters.
>
> **Safari (Browser)**
>
> At least 80,000 characters will work.
> I stopped testing after 80,000
> characters. Opera (Browser)
>
> At least 190,000 characters will work.
> I stopped testing after 190,000
> characters. Opera 9 for Windows
> continued to display a fully editable,
> copyable and pasteable URL in the
> location bar even at 190,000
> characters.
>
> **Apache (Server)**
>
> My early attempts to measure the
> maximum URL length in web browsers
> bumped into a server URL length limit
> of approximately 4,000 characters,
> after which Apache produces a "413
> Entity Too Large" error. I used the
> current up to date Apache build found
> in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4. The
> official Apache documentation only
> mentions an 8,192-byte limit on an
> individual field in a request.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum URL length in Internet Explorer is 2083 characters: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q208427/