# Does the Android Browser Application have a limit on the maximum length of a URL?

Tags: android, url, browser, limit

Does anyone know if there is a maximum restriction for the number of characters that the Android browser will accept in a GET URL?

I'm assuming any limit would translate to other WebKit based browsers such as the iPhone etc but if anyone knows differently, clarification on that would be great too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [414 Request-URI Too Large - Is this browser dependant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618013/414-request-uri-too-large-is-this-browser-dependant)