# Android: maximum length of url

Tags: android, url

Does anyone of you have an idea about the maximum length of a url in Android browser?

Comment: Duplicate but unanswered.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801339/does-the-android-browser-application-have-a-limit-on-the-maximum-length-of-a-url